# What is Untyped ActorSystem in Akka?

Tags: akka

While exploring Akka, I came across term Untyped ActorSystem.

What does it mean and is there typed ActorSystem too?If yes, how both differ?

Comment: https://michaelzg.com/akka/2018/09/03/akka-actor-fsm-comparison-part1/

Comment: Akka Untyped, or Akka Classic as it's called nowadays, is the older actor API of Akka. Before Akka Typed, the untyped version was just Akka, now it's actually called Akka Classic. See the note at the top of https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html for some more information. For new applications, it's recommended to start with the new API (as documented under https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html.